# save image from GLPaint Drawing into iPad ratina

Tags: ios, ipad, opengl-es, drawing

I am trying to save drawing as an image from `GLPaint` app from Apple sample code.
Saving the image is working fine in iPad(non-retina), but it issued when it runs on iPad(retina).
Whenever I run my app on iPad retina, then the image size is 1/4 from original.
Can anyone help me out from this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `glReadPixels` you seem to have wrong parameters inserted as width and height. You need to get the GL buffer width and height and insert them into `glReadPixels` instead of frame width and height. For retina those would be twice of a length of the frame dimension.

From the example mentioned those would be `backingWidth` and `backingHeight` and you should be able to get them anytime using:

```
glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH, &backingWidth);
glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT, &backingHeight);
```

So use `glReadPixels(0, 0, backingWidth, backingHeight, ...)` and be sure that the buffer you read to is also large enough. For RGBA that would be `backingWidth*backingHeight*4` bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Other methods that I have seen leak memory, here is a snipped I found and modified to capture an image from GLPaint.

```
-(BOOL)iPhoneRetina{
    return ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(displayLinkWithTarget:selector:)] && ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.0))?YES:NO;
}

void releasePixels(void *info, const void *data, size_t size) {
    free((void*)data);
}

-(UIImage *) glToUIImage{

    int imageWidth, imageHeight;

    int scale = [self iPhoneRetina]?2:1;

    imageWidth = self.frame.size.width*scale;
    imageHeight = self.frame.size.height*scale;

    NSInteger myDataLength = imageWidth * imageHeight * 4;

    // allocate array and read pixels into it.
    GLubyte *buffer = (GLubyte *) malloc(myDataLength);
    glReadPixels(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

    // make data provider with data.
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer, myDataLength, releasePixels);

    // prep the ingredients
    int bitsPerComponent = 8;
    int bitsPerPixel = 32;
    int bytesPerRow = 4 * imageWidth;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo =  kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast;
    CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;

    // make the cgimage

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(imageWidth, imageHeight, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, NO, renderingIntent);

    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:scale orientation:UIImageOrientationDownMirrored]; //Render image flipped, since OpenGL's data is mirrored

    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);

    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);

    return myImage;
}
```